# Is singleton a good idea for a visible state class in a card game?

Tags: objective-c, class, singleton

I am writing a card game in Objective-C, which I am relatively new to (I don't have very much programming experience at all). I have a *VisibleState* class that many objects need access to. In the game, there can of course only be one visible state, that means that it would not make sense to have several instances of the class.

Is this a situation where the *VisibleState* class should be a singleton class? I have done some research and many websites say that when only one instance of a class should exist, it can be a singleton class. However, I have also read that the singleton pattern often is misused and should be avoided. Should this visible state class be a singleton or should it be a regular one?

**EDIT**

The card game is currently written in C++. I asked the question in advance becasue I plan to rewrite it in Objective-C and wanted to structure the classes better than last time.

**EDIT 2**

```
// VisibleState.h

struct PublicPlayerInfo
{
    unsigned short m_unNumberOfHandCards = 0;
    unsigned short m_unNumberOfVisibleCards = 0;
    unsigned short m_unNumberOfHiddenCards = 0;
    Card m_acVisibleCards[3];
    Cardstack* m_pcPlayerHand = 0;

    bool m_bHasWon = false;
    std::string m_strName = "";
};

struct PublicTableInfo
{
    unsigned short m_unNumberOfTableCards = 0;
    unsigned short m_unNumberOfDrawCards = 0;
    unsigned short m_unNumberOfShitCards = 0;
    Card m_cTopCard;
};

struct VisibleState
{
    std::vector<PublicPlayerInfo> m_vecPublicPlayerInfo;
    PublicTableInfo m_sPublicTableInfo;
    unsigned short m_unCurrentPlayerNumber = 0;
};

// Player.h (only relevant code)

class Player
{
private:
    Cardstack m_cHand;
    Cardstack m_cVisible;
    Cardstack m_cHidden;
    const std::string m_strName;
    const Difficulty m_eDifficulty;
    const unsigned short m_unPlayerNumber;

    static FrontEnd* s_pcGUI;
    static AI* s_pcAI;
    static VisibleState* s_psVisibleState;
}; // Irrelevant code exlcuded


// Player.cpp

// I only took the simplest example function, if I would post all code, over five hundered lines would be used

Card Player::LayHandCard(const Card& rcCurrentTableCard, noc& runNumberOfCards)

{
    Card cLaidHandCard;
    noc unNumberOfCards;

    switch (m_eDifficulty)
    {
        case PERSON:
            cLaidHandCard = m_cHand.Take(s_pcGUI->LayHandCard(m_cHand, rcCurrentTableCard, unNumberOfCards));
            break;
        case LEVEL1:
            cLaidHandCard = m_cHand.Take(s_pcAI->Lv1_LayHandCard(m_cHand, rcCurrentTableCard, unNumberOfCards));
            break;
        case LEVEL2:
            cLaidHandCard = m_cHand.Take(s_pcAI->Lv2_LayHandCard(m_cHand, rcCurrentTableCard, unNumberOfCards));
            break;
        case LEVEL3:
            cLaidHandCard = m_cHand.Take(s_pcAI->Lv3_LayHandCard(m_cHand, rcCurrentTableCard, unNumberOfCards));
            break;
        case LEVEL4:
            cLaidHandCard = m_cHand.Take(s_pcAI->Lv4_LayHandCard(m_cHand, rcCurrentTableCard, unNumberOfCards));
            break;
        case LEVEL5:
            cLaidHandCard = m_cHand.Take(s_pcAI->Lv5_LayHandCard(m_cHand, rcCurrentTableCard, unNumberOfCards));
            break;
    }

    noc unNumberOfCardsLeft = unNumberOfCards;
    noc unNumberOfCardsLaid = 0;

    if (unNumberOfCardsLeft == 0)   // 0 means lay all, so a silly amount of checks must be done
        unNumberOfCardsLeft = 30000;
    else
        unNumberOfCardsLeft--;      // If 1 or more, it means that a special amount of cards will be taken, but one is already taken above
    unNumberOfCardsLaid++;

    for (noc unCurrentIndex = 0; unCurrentIndex < m_cHand.CountCards() && unNumberOfCardsLeft > 0; unCurrentIndex++)
    {
        if (m_cHand.Read(unCurrentIndex) == cLaidHandCard)
        {
            m_cHand.Take(unCurrentIndex);
            unNumberOfCardsLeft--;
            unNumberOfCardsLaid++;
        }
    }

    s_psVisibleState->m_vecPublicPlayerInfo[m_unPlayerNumber].m_unNumberOfHandCards -= unNumberOfCardsLaid;

    runNumberOfCards = unNumberOfCardsLaid;
    return cLaidHandCard;
}
```

**EDIT 3**

If it helps, here is a picture of the class structure:

[image]

Comment: What does the code look like in your VisibleState class?  how it looks and what it does is the best way to tell if it should be a singleton.

Comment: Currently it is only a struct (temporarly). It has three integers for the number of tablecards, drawcards and shitcards. It stores the topmost card. It also has an array of player info, which includes the number of hand cards, the number of visible cards and the player's name.

Comment: The class would be used by the AI function (read-only), the player objects (read-write) and the printing function (read-only).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a VisibleState class that many objects need access to...I have also read that the singleton pattern often is misused

You're abusing the pattern if your motivation is: "I need to access this object from lots of different places, and it'll be so easy if I just make it a singleton because then I can just use the global accessor to get the object from anywhere." Since you're new to programming it may not be immediately obvious *why* that's bad. Here are two problems that kind of thinking creates:

1. You're locking yourself into an assumption about how this class can be used, and that may not be valid at some point down the road. You may only need one instance of `VisibleState` now, but maybe you'll need two or more when you add a multiplayer feature to your game in a month or two. Maybe you'll want to save snapshots at different points in the game, and it'd be handy to do that by simply making copies of the current visible state. Don't confuse "I only need one" with "there must never ever be more than one."
2. When you have easy access to a single object from anywhere in the program, any part of the program can change that object. This is often a problem with global variables, and using a singleton because its easy to access from anywhere means that the singleton object is essentially the same as a global variable. Bugs caused by one part of the program changing the object when another part doesn't expect it to change can be hard to reproduce, hard to find, and hard to fix.

Plenty of people use and abuse singletons and will tell you that all the criticism is overblown, that things will work out fine, etc. There's some truth to that -- you can write a perfectly useable program using singletons, and possibly save yourself some time. You might not care about future flexibility, and you might be willing to commit to never having more than one instance of `VisibleState`. Just remember that using a singleton for it's global access is a shortcut, and like other shortcuts it can work out well or it can bite you. You say that you "structure the classes better than last time," so it sounds like you'd be better off thinking about how your objects relate to each other than just throwing in the towel and taking the easy approach.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest it looks like you are overcomplicating your class structure.  You should have table, players, and cards classes.  Visible should be a property of the card, not a class on its own.  If anything would be a singleton, it should be the table.  It's hard to give you an exact answer without seeing code.

Comment: Okay, what code do you need? Is it the VisibleState and the Player class?

Comment: Yes, anything that can give me a better handle of the STRUCTURE of your program.